# Dynamic symbol lookup fails with statically embedded Python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, dynamic, lookup

I'm building a Mac OS X application that is to embed Python. My application is technically a bundle (i.e. its main executable is MH_BUNDLE); it's a plug-in for another application. I'd like it to embed Python statically, but want to be able to load extensions dynamically.

I did the following: I included a whole library (`-force_load path/to/libpython2.7.a`), also reexported all Python symbols (`-exported_symbol_list path/to/list`), and added the `-u _PyMac_Error`, which I got using [this linking advice](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html#linking-requirements). The bundle itself loads fine, all internal Python code appears to work, but it fails when it it tries to import a dynamic library (`time.so`) with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ImportError: dlopen(/<stripped>/time.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyExc_OverflowError
  Referenced from: /<stripped>/time.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

This symbol is a part of Python API and it must be in my bundle already. I can check this:

```
nm -g Build/Debug/pyfm | grep _PyExc_OverflowError
00172884 D _PyExc_OverflowError
0019cde0 D _PyExc_OverflowError
```

(It's listed twice because I have two architectures, i386 and ppc).

The `time.so` doesn't reference anything, which, as I understand, is by design:

```
otool -L "/<stripped>/time.so"
/<stripped>/time.so (architecture ppc):
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 88.3.11)
/<stripped>/time.so (architecture i386):
/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 88.3.11)
```

My problem appears to be similar to [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue4434), but it's the other way round: I do link Python statically, while the other poster linked it dynamically (an our platforms are different too). For him static linking solved the problem.

Why doesn't it find the symbol?

**Update.** I suspect it happens because the main app loads its plug-ins (and thus my bundle) with `RTLD_LOCAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “update” I made suggests it right: the main plug-in bundle is loaded locally (`RTLD_LOCAL`), so nobody can see any symbols there, unless using explicit `dlopen` followed by `dlsym`.

If it were Linux I could promote the bundle to the global namespace by `dlopen`ing it again with the `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag, but under Mac OS X this doesn't work. But Mac OS X nicely packs stuff into bundles, so I just made a dynamic library and put it into the plug-in bundle directory. The library loads automatically as `RTLD_GLOBAL` and all Python symbols are available.