# What's the meaning of dylib files?

Tags: elf, mach-o, dynamic-library

My C++ compiler creates "dylib" files which contain dynamic libraries. Whats the difference between .dylib and .so files?

And what is the difference between files in Mach-O format and files in an ELF format? I have to build files for later use under iOS (static libraries only/Mach-O) and Android (ELF).

Thanx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that:

> One Mach-O feature that hits many people by surprise is the strict
>   distinction between shared libraries and dynamically loadable modules.
>   On ELF systems both are the same; any piece of shared code can be used
>   as a library and for dynamic loading. Use otool -hv some_file to see
>   the filetype of some_file.
>
> Mach-O shared libraries have the file type MH_DYLIB and carry the
>   extension .dylib. They can be linked against with the usual static
>   linker flags, e.g. -lfoo for libfoo.dylib. However, they can not be
>   loaded as a module. (Side note: Shared libraries can be loaded
>   dynamically through an API. However, that API is different from the
>   API for bundles and the semantics make it useless for an dlopen()
>   emulation. Most notably, shared libraries can not be unloaded.) [This
>   is no longer true—you can use dlopen() with both dylibs and bundles.
>   However, dylibs still can't be unloaded.]
>
> Loadable modules are called "bundles" in Mach-O speak. They have the
>   file type MH_BUNDLE. Since no component involved cares about it, they
>   can carry any extension. The extension .bundle is recommended by
>   Apple, but most ported software uses .so for the sake of
>   compatibility. Bundles can be dynamically loaded and unloaded via dyld
>   APIs, and there is a wrapper that emulates dlopen() on top of that
>   API. [dlopen is now the preferred API.] It is not possible to link
>   against bundles as if they were shared libraries. However, it is
>   possible that a bundle is linked against real shared libraries; those
>   will be loaded automatically when the bundle is loaded.
>
> To compile a normal shared library on OS X, you should use -dynamiclib
>   and the extension .dylib. -fPIC is the default.

Comment: Can you add the source? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339910