# Linking to boost::program_options does not work properly

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-program-options

The following library files exist:

```
cls /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.51.0/lib $ ls libboost_program*
libboost_program_options-mt.a       libboost_program_options-mt.dylib
```

I include the following header with `#include <boost/program_options.hpp>`:

```
cls /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.51.0/include $ ls boost/program_options.hpp
boost/program_options.hpp
```

I try to link the libraries with

```
-lboost_program_options-mt
-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.51.0/lib
```

(I assume that the name of the library is derived from the file name minus the "lib" and the file ending. If I try the name `boost_program_options` (without `-mt`), I get `ld: library not found for -lboost_program_options`)

This is my main function using the library:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    namespace opts = boost::program_options;

    opts::options_description desc("EnsembleClustering options");
    desc.add_options()
            ("hello", "produce greeting");

    opts::variables_map vmap;
    opts::store(opts::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vmap);
    opts::notify(vmap);

    if (vmap.count("hello")) {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Why does this setup give me a `symbol(s) not found` error?

```
make all 
Building target: EnsembleClustering-DPar
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
/usr/local/bin/g++-4.7 -L"/Users/cls/workspace/STINGER/OpenMP Debug" -L"/Users/cls/workspace/gtest/lib" -L/usr/local/Cellar/log4cxx/0.10.0/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.51.0/lib -fopenmp -std=c++11 -o "EnsembleClustering-DPar"  ./src/scoring/EdgeScoring.o ./src/scoring/ModularityScoring.o  ./src/overlap/test/OverlapGTest.o  ./src/overlap/Overlapper.o ./src/overlap/RegionGrowingOverlapper.o  ./src/matching/Matcher.o ./src/matching/Matching.o ./src/matching/ParallelMatcher.o  ./src/io/test/InputGTest.o  ./src/io/CSVWriter.o ./src/io/GraphFromAdjacencies.o ./src/io/GraphIO.o ./src/io/GraphReader.o ./src/io/METISGraphReader.o ./src/io/METISParser.o ./src/io/METISToGraph.o  ./src/graph/test/GraphGTest.o ./src/graph/test/STINGERGTest.o  ./src/graph/Graph.o ./src/graph/GraphGenerator.o  ./src/ensemble/test/EnsembleGTest.o  ./src/ensemble/EnsembleClusterer.o  ./src/coarsening/test/CoarseningGTest.o  ./src/coarsening/ClusterContracter.o ./src/coarsening/ClusteringProjector.o ./src/coarsening/Contracter.o ./src/coarsening/GraphContraction.o ./src/coarsening/MatchingContracter.o  ./src/clustering/test/ClusteringGTest.o  ./src/clustering/base/Clustering.o ./src/clustering/base/ClusteringGenerator.o ./src/clustering/base/Modularity.o ./src/clustering/base/QualityMeasure.o  ./src/clustering/algo/test/ClusteringAlgoGTest.o  ./src/clustering/algo/Clusterer.o ./src/clustering/algo/LabelPropagation.o ./src/clustering/algo/ParallelAgglomerativeClusterer.o  ./src/aux/test/AuxGTest.o  ./src/aux/Noise.o ./src/aux/RandomInteger.o ./src/aux/RandomProbability.o ./src/aux/Timer.o  ./src/EnsembleClustering.o   -lSTINGER -lgtest -llog4cxx -lboost_program_options-mt
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::__debug::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*) in EnsembleClustering.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [EnsembleClustering-DPar] Error 1
```

EDIT: Checking the library files with `lipo` gives

```
cls /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.51.0/lib $ lipo -detailed_info libboost_program_options-mt.a libboost_program_options-mt.dylib 
input file libboost_program_options-mt.a is not a fat file
input file libboost_program_options-mt.dylib is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libboost_program_options-mt.a is architecture: x86_64
Non-fat file: libboost_program_options-mt.dylib is architecture: x86_64
```

I'd like to link the static library.

Comment: @Caribou I've read that question before posting. Where exactly do you see the solution to my problem there?

Comment: apologies I just realised I'm wrong as well :(

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Did you try linking with the static version of the library to see if it works? Could it be possible that the installed lib is 32 bits instead of 64?

Comment: I think Alberto may be right, although I was able to build this no problem on 64 bit g++ (4.1.2) against a 32 bit library. `/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.33.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386`

Comment: did you try g++ -static?

Comment: @AlbertoMiranda I want to link the static library, not the dynamic one. How do I tell the linker to do this? How can I check for 32 bit vs 64 bit?

Comment: Just add it to the command line as if it was an object file, that is without using the `-l` flag. I believe you need to include the `.a` extension as well. In my answer you can see how to check the arch.

Comment: I added the `-static` flag to the linker but this gives me: `ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o`. I gues I'll have to do without `boost::program_options`.

Comment: how did you build the boost libraries? Which toolchain was used?

Answer (score 4):

### **Read the error message**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::__debug::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)", referenced from:
      boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*) in EnsembleClustering.o
```

It very clearly says, **missing symbol `std::__debug::vector`**, note that the `std::__debug` namespace is key here. I suspect you've built your source code using iterator debugging with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` but are attempting to link against a library that hasn't, such as boost program options. You didn't show us how you built your translation units, so here is a [sscce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3df10c72ae3c83fa2b3b34929605324f-6b67ab5871989e18c441dfd6c81d8b56):

```
$ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -pthread main.cpp -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -lboost_program_options && ./a.out
/tmp/cca1jwUx.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x319): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::__debug::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There are a few ways to solve this

- remove the `-DGLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag from translation units including the program options headers.
- consult your boost package maintainer to see if they offer a version built with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. Some variants on Linux do, you might ask around the MacPorts or brew users mailing lists.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're specifying the location for includes, libraries and providing the appropriate `.dylib`, the only problem I can think of is that the library that you're linking to doesn't have an x86_64 arch in it.

Try checking the library with either `file` or `lipo`. If it doesn't show x86_64, then that's the problem.

Comment: I was tempted to suggest simply creating a sym link called `libboost_program_options-mt.so` file to the `libboost_program_options-mt.dylib` file, but a bit of reading of [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158783/whats-the-meaning-of-dylib-files) convinced me that it may be a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: See the edit to my question. The .dylib is 64bit. The `.a` with which I want to link, also?

Comment: `file` provides few information for `.a` files. Try with `lipo` instead.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would not work. Were you able to link to the static library?

Comment: @AlbertoMiranda No. I can't think of a reason either. Thanks for your help, but I'll use this option parser instead: http://optionparser.sourceforge.net/