# In python after I import a module is there a way of finding what physical file it was loaded from?

Tags: python, module, package, loading

Something's acting up in my math package I think and I want to ensure I'm loading the correct module. How do I check the physical file location of loaded modules in python?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `__file__` attribute:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'
```

Note that built-in modules written in C and statically linked to the interpreter do not have this attribute:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

An other way to obtain the path to the file is using [`inspect.getfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile). It raises `TypeError` if the object passed is a built.in module, class or function.

On a side note, you should avoid using names that conflict with language built-ins or standard library modules. So, I'd suggest you to rename your `math` package to something else, or, if it is part of a package like `mypackage.math`, to avoid importing it directly and use `mypackage.math` instead.

Comment: Interesting.  Why does my math module have a `.file` attribute and yours doesn't?

Comment: @Mark Probably on Mac OS X the `math` module is not statically linked to the interpreter. (I guess is OSX by the `lib-dynload` in the path)
It probably has to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx)

Comment: I'm on linux, so I don't get the .file attr. Anyway to check this? Then again I guess this means I'm probably loading the correct one.

Comment: If the module has not `__file__` attribute then you are loading the module from the standard library. Whether it's the correct one depends on which one you wanted to import.

Comment: I'm actually on Linux - Fedora 14.

Comment: @Mark Then I have no idea. Did you install it with `yum` or in some other way?

Comment: It was the Python included with the base install.  After some Googling, the best I can come up with is that `built-in` modules (like sys or thread) do not have the attribute.  Which Linux distro are you running?

Comment: Kubuntu 12.04. The documentation explicitly says that C modules statically linked to the interpreter do not have the attribute. Why `math` is sometimes statically linked and sometimes not I really have no idea.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are correct about, by `built-in`, they mean they are directly in libpython.

Answer (score 1):

Check `themodule.__file__`.

```
import urllib
print urllib.__file__
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so'
```

Comment: May I know what are some common use cases of this utility ?