# How to add code in runtime

Tags: c++, windows

I was searching through stackoverflow questions but none of them answered my question. I have a game engine and I want to load player AI (written in c++) in runtime.

1. Click on button, file dialog appears
2. Choose file with AI (.dll or something?)
3. Click on 'start' button, game starts using AI's that I add.

AI could be a method or whole class, it doesn't matter. I think I should generate .dll but I not sure how to do that. This class should look like this:

```
class PlayerAI
{
    void computeSomething(list of argument, Object& output)
    {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming pure Windows platform since none specified -

If you want to inject DLL, first obtain a handle to it using LoadLibrary-function like so:

```
HINSTANCE handleLib; 
handleLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("YourDLL.dll"));
```

You may then obtain a function pointer to a specific function in the lib. Like this:

```
FUNC_PTR func;
func = (FUNC_PTR) GetProcAddress(handleLib, "yourFunc");
```

Then you can call the function like so:

```
 (func) (L"TESTSTRING HERE");
```

When done, call FreeLibrary(libhandle)

How to declare a function as exported is in VS for instance like this (this is needed to mark your function in your DLL that you precompile:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl yourFunc(LPWSTR someString)
{
   //Code here... 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention already compiled DLLs, you want to look at [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That's how you do runtime loads of DLLs and extract specific functions from them.

Examples can be found under [Using Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Note: DLL exports don't usually play nice with C++ classes. You'll probably want to use a C compatible interface (that can use C++ classes under the hood if needed); C++'s name mangling and ABI is just not well suited to this use case.

Comment: If the question were flagged "Windows" in any way, this would be a sure upvote. [This question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24089878/60281) handles the POSIX part of the computing world.

Comment: @DevSolar You mean in addition to the note ".dll or something" in the question?

Comment: @Angew: In Linux: `echo "int main() {}" > somefile.dll` Whoops! You can name files anything. :P

Comment: @Angew: I don't base assumptions on statements that include "or something". ;-) Besides, there's always the future visitor to consider, who will come here based on the question title most likely. ;-)