# How to make a .so executable on OSX?

Tags: c, macos, shared-libraries

I have a simple C library that I compile to a `.so` file on my linux machine. I'd like to do the same on my Mac, but after I compile and move the library to `/usr/local/lib`, but I'm not sure how to link it seeing as `ldconfig` isn't a thing.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You'd start by reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Linux has `.so` files, OSX has `.dylib` files. The process is similar, you just invoke compiler as in

```
clang -dynamiclib -o libname.dylib sources.c
```

Comment: Yes, but `.so` files are executable on osx as well are they not? I have several in `/usr/local/lib` on OSX right now.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx