# Encrypting and compressing using p7zip

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, zlib, qt5.6, quazip

I am trying to replace the usage of 7zip in my QT Xcode project. Currently the files are archived using a password and my project on Windows uses 7z when accessing automatically opens the file. 
I have found p7zip to be the port of 7zip for linux/mac
The objectives are:

1. Open existing 7zip archived files with password
2. Save stream with password as a single file.

I built with the following commands

```
$cd path/to/p7zip
$cp makefile.macosx_64bits makefile.machine
$make 7z
```

It built without any errors but I am not able to find *.a or *.dylib files. Instead I find the following in the bin folder

1. 7z
2. 7z.so
3. Codecs

Codecs has Rar.so

That is a linux lib file isn't it?

I am very new to the Mac dev, so any help or suggestion would be helpful. I am not able to find an example program too.

Comment: I am taking a huge guess here and stating, lzma/7zip is not supported :(

Comment: You don't have to port 7-zip to Linux and  MacOS X, there is p7zip: http://p7zip.sourceforge.net

Comment: I was experimenting with that and looks like it is possible to get it to Mac and my project. However, I see "make all2" command creating .so files which is linux specific right? Mac needs *.a files and *.dylib. I do not get either (http://superuser.com/questions/548349/how-can-i-install-7zip-so-i-can-run-it-from-terminal-on-os-x). I need to use the features within my application and not really a clt or gui..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between .so and .dylib on osx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx)

Comment: @Elijan9 can you help me with question related to p7zip https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558436/command-to-extract-password-zip-file-using-p7zip