# convert from .dylib to .so

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dylib, .so

Hello in a previous question I've asked about compiling to .dylib, after having asked what OBS uses as a plugin.. .so or .dylib.. 1 of their devs responded with .dylib.. so I created my project as a .dylib..

However I just found out that he / she has provided incorrect information and that my program must be build to .so

is it possible to convert from .dylib to .so, my .dylib file is coded in Swift.. is there a Swift to c++ converter anywhere? If not how can I create a .so project in Xcode on OSX?

Comment: There are some compatibility between .so and .dylib. Both can be loaded with dl functions. A quick search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx

Comment: @Calvin I did find that, but is there a way to convert my Swift code to c++ using some sortof a convert.. or is it possible to just build to .so from Swift, I presume that the latter isn't possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to convert .dylib to .so as far as I've found.