# How to compile .c .h .so file?

Tags: c, macos

Another company gives me three files(demo.c,api.h,libapi.so). they told me that't enough for develop. I'm confuse how to build these thing together. 
I use gcc demo.c -o demo -l libapi.so . But's it's said "ld: library not found". I use Mac OS system. Some websites said i should use Linux to use .so file. what should I do?

Comment: `.so` files are not OSX. `-l libapi.so` ? Try `-lapi` flag. You may also have to provide search path for a non-standard library `-L./` (this means it is in the current directory).

Comment: If the so file is in your current directory try -l ./libapi.so

Comment: As asked, this is not related to embedded systems!

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2339910/929459 ?

Comment: Generally speaking, Mac OS X uses `.dylib` and `.bundle` for shared libraries (with `.dylib` being dynamic libraries loaded when the program starts and `.bundle` being libraries loaded via `dlopen()` etc after the program starts — at least in theory).  It seems likely that the `.so` file is incorrect for OS X.  What do you get when you run `file libapi.so` and what does `otool -L libapi.so` have to say?  If the answers don't include `Mach-O`, then you're likely to need to go back to the supplier (for source or object code for OS X). Try: `gcc -o demo demo.c libapi.so` (no `-l`); it might work.

Comment: Note that using linker options `-l xyz` means that the linker should look for `libxyz.dylib` or `libxyz.a` on OS X.  Specifying `-l libapi.so` means that the linker is looking for `liblibapi.so.dylib` or `liblibapi.so.a` and (not very surprisingly) is not finding either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*.so is  "shared object" it works only on Linux. The Windows counterpart of *.so is DLL.These are combiled object code.

What you have to do is 
1] "compile" your .c to .o [object file]
2] "Link"  the new .o file with the .so

Comment: There might be other systems which use `.so` extension.

Comment: Solaris uses `.so` for shared objects; so does modern AIX, IIRC.  And the normal extension on Mac OS X are `.dylib` and `.bundle`.