# Building and linking shared Tensorflow library on OSX El Capitan to call from Ruby via Swig

Tags: ruby, macos, tensorflow, swig, bazel

I'm trying to help build a Ruby wrapper around [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html) using [Swig](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Ruby.html#Ruby_nn11). Currently, I'm stuck at making a shared build, `.so`, and exposing its C/C++ headers to Ruby. So the question is: How do I build a `libtensorflow.so` shared build including the full Tensorflow library so it's available as a shared library on OSX El Capitan (note: `/usr/lib/` is read-only on El Capitan)?

#### Background

In this [ruby-tensorflow](https://github.com/chrhansen/ruby-tensorflow) project, I need to package a Tensorflow `.bundle` file, but whenever I `irb -Ilib -rtensorflow` or try to run the specs `rspec`, I get and errors that the basic numeric types are not defined, but they are clearly defined [here](https://github.com/chrhansen/ruby-tensorflow/blob/master/ext/files/tensor_c_api.h#L73).

I'm guessing this happens because my `.so`-file was not created properly or something is not linked as it should. C++/Swig/Bazel are not my strong sides, I'd like to focus on learning Tensorflow and building a good wrapper in Ruby, but I'm pretty stuck at this point getting to that fun part!

What I've done:

1. `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
2. `cd tensorflow`
3. `bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so` (wait 10-15min on my machine)
4. Copied the generated `libtensorflow.so` (166.6 MB) to the [`/ext`-folder](https://github.com/chrhansen/ruby-tensorflow/tree/master/ext)
5. Run the `ruby extconf.rb`, `make`, and `make install` [described in the project](https://github.com/Arafatk/ruby-tensorflow#installation)
6. Run `rspec`

In desperation, I've also gone through the official [installation from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources) several times, but I don't know if that, the last `sudo pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl`-step even creates a shared build or just exposes a Python interface.

The guy, Arafat, who made the [original repository](https://github.com/Arafatk/ruby-tensorflow) and made the instructions that I've followed, says his `libtensorflow.so` is <strike>4.5 GB on his Linux machine – so over 20X the size of the shared build on my OSX machine.</strike> UPDATE1: he says his `libtensorflow.so`-build is **302.2 MB**, 4.5GB was the size of the entire tensorflow folder.

Any help or alternative approaches are very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more digging around, discovering `otool` (thanks Kristina) and better understanding what a [`.so`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx)-file is, the solution didn't require much change in my setup:

#### Shared Build

```
# Clone source files
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
cd tensorflow
# Build library
bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
# Copy the newly shared build/library to /usr/local/lib
sudo cp bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow.so /usr/local/lib
```

#### Calling from Ruby using Swig

Follow the steps here, https://github.com/chrhansen/ruby-tensorflow#install-ruby-tensorflow, to run Swig, create a Makefile and `make`

When you run `make` you should see a line saying:

```
$ make
$ linking shared-object libtensorflow.bundle
```

If your shared build is not accessible you'll see something like:

```
$ ld: library not found for -ltensorflow
```

#### Simple tutorial

For those starting on this adventure, using C/C++ libraries in Ruby, this post was a good tutorial for me: http://engineering.gusto.com/simple-ruby-c-extensions-with-swig/

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you actually want a .so, I think you want a .dylib (see [What are the differences between .so and .dylib on osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx)).  You're forcing Bazel to build a .so by specifying `libtensorflow.so` as the target, build this instead:

```
bazel build //tensorflow
```

(`//tensorflow` is shorthand for `//tensorflow:tensorflow`, which is "build the tensorflow target."  Specifying an exact file you want forces Bazel to build that file, if possible.)

Once you have a .dylib, you can check its contents with `otool`:

```
 otool -L bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow.dylib
```

Not sure if this will solve all your problems, but worth a try.

Comment: Hi kristina, thanks! Well `bazel build //tensorflow` resulted in `ERROR: no such target '//tensorflow:tensorflow': target 'tensorflow' defined by ...`. So I actually needed the `libtensorflow.so`. However, your `otool`-comment lead me in the right direction. `otool -hv libtensorflow.so` told me the bazel output was a `DYLIB`-filetype (so I guess I could just change the extension to `.dylib`), and hinted that my build was actually ok.

Comment: Cool! Sorry for the bum lead, tensorflow actually literally defines the target as a [.so](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/BUILD#L154)!  I assumed they were building it as a library.  Glad it worked out!

Comment: No worries, it forced me to actually look into the BUILD-file and see that tensorflow.so was the only target. Since I read the .so vs .dylib post and knowing that the Tensorflow-team had made Tensorflow available for Mac I concluded I was on the right path.