# How to force ./configure to generated shared library rather than bundle

Tags: bundle, shared, configure, autoreconf

I have downloaded and built the famous open source software `gridlab-d` on OS X:

```
svn checkout https://svn.code.sf.net/p/gridlab-d/code/branch/3.2 gridlab-d
cd gridlab-d
autoreconf -isf
./configure
make
make install
```

The above process generated some `.so` libraries and the software works fine through its command line interface. However I want to develop my own c++ code and link against the `.so` libraries. This is not possible since the generated `.so` files are [bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx) and not shared libraries. How can I force `./configure` to generate shared libraries instead?